# Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin. "https://www.payumoney.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match

Tags: android, webview, payumoney, cross-origin-read-blocking

payumoney integrated into my website and now I am using it in my mobile web view. but it gives me this issue and page do not load.it shows a white screen instead of the page.

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://checkout.citruspay.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.payumoney.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Does anyone know how to overcome this security issue?